# Why is the semiclassical approximation of the abelian Chern-Simons theory exact?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematics, topological-field-theory, semiclassical, chern-simons-theory

I was told that in abelian Chern-Simons theory (say, with a general level matrix $K$), semiclassical approximation is exact because there is no trivalent vertex, which in non-abelian case makes the perturbative series factorially divergent. **Why should the converging perturbative series in this case give us an exact result?** For instnace, there might be some terms which vanish to all order of perturbation, which is actually the case for non-abelian complex Chern-Simons theory where we consider trans-series, taking into account all the instanton effects, and then do the resurgent analysis. Why is this not the case for abelian Chern-Simons theory?

I am also curious if the exactness of semiclassical approximation in the abelian Chern-Simons theory is somehow related to that of supersymmetric field theories where the effect of bosons and fermions cancel each other out, making the situation localized near the vacua.